SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' in typescript monorepo project
I am working on a microservice application with Nest.js in a pnpm monorepo workspace. I have a type package where I defined all the types of my project.
When I try to use a type in my services, an error is thrown:
enter image description here
Here is how I import the types:
enter image description here
I use the dto this way:
enter image description here
Here is the hierachy of the types package and its package.json.
enter image description here
{
    "name": "@aquaexplore/types",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "type": "module",
    "main": "index.ts",
    "types": "index.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc --build"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.3.1",
        "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
        "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
        "zod": "^3.22.4"
    }
}


Basically in the index.ts files I just export the classes in the different dtos and entities at the same level.

Copying error messages is better than screenshots :)

It seems to be a problem with the compilation steps, a minimal reproduction will help
